# R method of summarising vector up to certain quantile(s)

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, quantile

I have data relating to 36 regions of interest (ROI), approx. 380 pixels per ROI.
My data is like:

```
      ROI_name    T_K
1   bt_full_05 303.88
1.1 bt_full_05 303.93
1.2 bt_full_05 303.72
1.3 bt_full_05 303.43
1.4 bt_full_05 302.93
1.5 bt_full_05 302.93
...
36.362 bt_full_40 301.65
36.363 bt_full_40 301.47
36.364 bt_full_40 301.52
36.365 bt_full_40 302.02
36.366 bt_full_40 303.28
36.367 bt_full_40 303.78
```

I want to compute mean T_K for each ROI, but filter out values below a given quantile, e.g. 0.25, and output the mean of values up to that quantile. Ideally I could report mean T_K for several quantiles, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5...
I have:

```
groupquant <- cleared_data %>% group_by(ROI_name) %>% 
  summarise(quants = quantile(T_K, 0.1))
```

which gives me the quantiles. But this

```
groupquant <- cleared_data %>% group_by(ROI_name) %>% 
  filter(cleared_data$T_K <= quantile(T_K, 0.1)) #%>%
```

throws

> Error: Result must have length 392, not 14082

I'm getting nowhere! Cheers, Andrew.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you use `filter(T_K <= quantile(T_K, 0.1))` instead.

Comment: jazzurro is correct. The problem is that by using `cleared_data$T_K` you are comparing the full vector of length 14082 with a subgroup of that vector of length 392. Just use `T_K`

Comment: thanks heaps @jazzurro, that goes well. but i also want to compute mean of vals < the quantile in each ROI, also several different quantiles. any further clues, pls?

Answer (score 0):

I think the sample data is a bit small to demonstrate that you wanna do. So I created my own data, which is called `foo`. For each `ROI_name`, I removed some data with `filter()`. All values which are smaller than `quantile(T_K, 0.25)` are removed. Then, I decided to take values for two quantile points (i.e., 0.5 and 0.75). In the `summarize()` part, I am getting a vector with two numeric values and creating a data frame for each group. Finally, I used `unnest()` to create the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(111)

foo <- tibble(ROI_name = rep(c("bt_full_05", "bt_full_40", "bt_full_2"), each = 30),
              T_K = runif(n = 90, min = 0, max = 300))

group_by(foo, ROI_name) %>% 
filter(T_K > quantile(T_K, 0.25)) %>% 
summarize(temp = list(enframe(quantile(x = T_K, prob = c(0.5, 0.75)),
                              name = "percentile"))) %>% 
unnest(temp)

  ROI_name   percentile value
  <chr>      <chr>      <dbl>
1 bt_full_05 50%         157.
2 bt_full_05 75%         183.
3 bt_full_2  50%         157.
4 bt_full_2  75%         229.
5 bt_full_40 50%         192.
6 bt_full_40 75%         237.
```